# it took a lot of effort

Tags: phrases, infinitives, dummy-pronouns

a. It took a lot of effort for the bridge to be constructed.

Is that sentence grammatically correct?

The intended meaning is that constructing the bridge took a lot of effort.

---

I am used to sentences like:

b. It took a lot of effort for us to construct the bridge.

and

c. It took us a lot of effort to construct the bridge.

I am not sure (a) is correct.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the grammar, but I find it less idiomatic than (b) and (c) because it seems to imply that the bridge made the effort.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. Omitting the actor is a common technique when you want to focus on the action or the object instead of who did it. You often see this in discussions of historical events -- it took ten years to end the war; it took three years to build the cathedral; it took 200 tons of concrete to build the aqueduct.